# Temperature sensing with ADS1115

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, adc, temperature, non-linear

I am using an ADS1115 as an analog to digital converter to measure temperature. I am using an RTD100 temperature sensor to measure a temperature range of -40 to 150 degree celsius but the resistance vs. temperature table of the temperature sensor is non linear.

How can I convert the temperature range of -40 to 150 degree celsius
to a proportional voltage of 0-5V so that I can measure it with an ADS1115?

Temperature vs. resistance table of RTD100:

[image]

[image]

This is a reference circuit to which an RTD100 is connected.  It converts the temperature range of 0-200 degrees celsius to 0-5V but I want to design a circuit that converts (-40)-150 degree celsius to 0-5V.

How should I calculate the resistance values connected to the opamp?

Comment: Use R-divider.  R1 - is RTD100 connected to grownd and measured point. R2 - const resistor, connect to Vdd and  measured point.  R = R1 + R2. I=Vdd / (R1+R2).  U=I*R. Umeasured= R1 * Vdd / (R1+R2)

Comment: If the power supply 5v, Umeasured-max can be not highter then 2,5 (cause Divider use). 5 volts at the output is possible if there is an additional power supply with a voltage of 10V or highter.

Comment: but how can i get linear relationship with resistance and voltage?@nick_n_a

Comment: When R2 greater then R1 many times - the value R1+R2 - is roughly equal R2. And U= R1*Vdd/R2(roughly)

Comment: @nick_n_a i am actually not clear with the circuit diagram

Comment: Lock at your circuit. R1 and RS - is diveder. Middle point is  U(-40)=843*5/(4990+843)=0,7v (before amp).  U(150)=1573*5/(4990+1573)=1,19v. In this case you need of amp.

Comment: Why you need 5v? Your ADC is 16bit and can measure 0,001 v?  (1,19 - 0,7)/(-40-150)  = 0,5 / 200 = 1/400 - 0,0025. I think your ADS1115 can measure this value, and conversion table will be more simple than amp calculation. I recomend you R1 select from 800 to 1500 Ohm and build conversion table.

Comment: i didn't the concept of conversion table like i need to code it@nick_n_a

Comment: May be "Wheatstone bridge" helps you. Read about wheatstone bridge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply higher-order polynomial regression (second-order is enough) for establishing the relationship. There is a built-in function in Matlab and GNU Octave for establishing the relationship.
Besides, you may apply gradient descent to find the relationship (which is really tough).

I always use Octave for algorithm development. It's free and just 300 MB. Matlab is bulky and costly. All you have to do is to copy and paste the chart in a txt file.

https://github.com/SadatRafi/Thermistor-Curve-Fitting-Octave  I've uploaded my octave code and details in GitHub. I hope it might be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can roughly linearize the signal in an analog fashion by using a slightly non-constant current through the sensor that is partly proportional to the output voltage (a taste of positive feedback). You can easily linearize the signal so that it is (theoretically) perfect for any 3 points of your choosing, for example, 0%, 50% and 100% of your range.

However it's currently 2020 last I looked, and most instrumentation designers would read in the signal proportional to the **resistance** and use a simple algorithm such as evaluation of the Callendar-Van-Dusen equation to digitally convert the resistance reading to temperature.

Comment: do you have any references regarding the digitally convertion of resistance reading to temperature@Spehro Pefhany

Comment: Google "Callendar-Van-Dusen equation".